# Does Google Cloud Vision API detect font size in OCRed text?

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision

The most useful information to distinguish headers and footnotes in a book from the body text is font size and font type; GCV cannot distinguish font type, but can it distinguish between font size and superscript and subscript?

I tried makepdfgui but it couldn't distinguish font size.